# Ayuda con PHPMailerAutoload.php

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, phpmailer

Estoy intentando enviar un correo usando la librería de php que es PHPMailerAutoload.php
El motivo por el cual uso esta librería es para recuperar la contraseña de un usuario. NOTA: Estoy usando gmail.
El codigo lo tengo configurado de esta manera:

```
//Método getValor
function getValor($campo, $campoWhere, $valor) {
$ConexionBD = con();

$stmt = $ConexionBD->prepare("SELECT $campo FROM cliente_correo WHERE $campoWhere = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $valor);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num = $stmt->num_rows;

if ($num > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($_campo);
    $stmt->fetch();
    return $_campo;
}
else {
    return null;    
}
}

function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo){
require 'php/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->Username = 'usuario@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '*************';

$mail->setFrom('usuario@gmail.com'); //REMITENTE 
$mail->addAddress($email, $nombre); //DESTINATARIO

$mail->Subject = $asunto;
$mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

//ENVIO DEL EMAIL ...
if($mail->send() == false) {
    //return true;
    echo "No se pudo enviar ";
    echo "Error de PHPMailer  ".' '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
    //return false;
    echo "El correo se envió ;)";
}
```

}

Mi formulario HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" role="form" class=" form-horizontal login-form">        
            <fieldset>
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
                        <input type="email" name="recover_mail" class="form-control" 
                               placeholder="Introduce tu correo electrónico" required >
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="enviar_email">Enviar</button>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    ¿No te has registrado? <a href="cliente_registrar.php">Registrate ahora</a>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
</form>
```

El método POST lo tengo así:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $_POST['recover_mail']);

if(!isEmail($email)) {
    $errors[] = "Debe ingresar un email valido";
}

if(emailExiste($email)) {
    //hace una consulta a la tabla cliente_correo
    $user_id = getValor('idCliente', 'correoElectronico', $email);
    $correoElectronico = getValor('correoElectronico', 'correoElectronico', $email);

    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/Monte-Carlo_v5/cliente_pass_change.php?user_id='.$user_id;

    $asunto = 'Recuperar Password';
    $cuerpo = "Hola $email:<br><br>Se ha solicitado un reinicio de contrase&ntilde;a, por favor, para procesar este paso haz clic a la siguiente direcci&oacute;,: 
        <a href='$url'>Ok, Cambiar Password!!</a> ";

    if(enviarEmail($email, $correoElectronico, $asunto, $cuerpo)) {

        echo '
            <p class="text-success">Hemos enviado un correo electrónico a la direccion $email para restablecer tu password.</p>
            <br><br>
            <a href="cliente_login.php">Iniciar sesion</a>
            ';

        exit;
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Error al enviar email";
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = "El email no existe";
}
```

}

Y este es el error que tengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error significa que `PHPMailer` no puede ponerse en contacto con el servidor `SMTP` que haz especificado en la propiedad Host.

Puedes hacer una comprobación al puerto de SMTP (Terminal):

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

Si el puerto `587` no funciona puedes probar con `25` o `465` y usas cual te funciona, se debe mencionar que el puerto `25` no siempre soporta el cifrado.

En el siguiente link te deja posibles soluciones al problema: 
[Troubleshooting PHPMailer Problems](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: Gracias aldanux